# Is there any limit for iOS SSO on multiple apps

Tags: ios, facebook, single-sign-on, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

Facebook [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/#multipleapps) defines that if you have multiple apps using a single Facebook app ID you will need to add a configuration to the **App Dashboard** to list the URL Scheme Suffix information for the apps that share one ID.

My question is there any limit on the number of suffix I can use? (lets say I'm a platform if you wonder why).

Cheers,
 Roger.